# Authenticate in SharePoint with OpenLDAP

Tags: forms-authentication, ldap

I've been trying to use openLdap for SharePoint authentication.
I followed this document http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806890.aspx

but I don't know how to customize the foolllowing xml:

```
<membership defaultProvider="LdapMembershipProvider"> 
 <providers> 
 <add  
 name="LdapMembership"  
 type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LDAPMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"  
 server="DC"  
 port="389"  
 useSSL="false"  
 userDNAttribute="distinguishedName"  
 userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName"  
 userContainer="CN=Users,DC=userName,DC=local"  
 userObjectClass="person"  
 userFilter="(|(ObjectCategory=group)(ObjectClass=person))"  
 scope="Subtree"  
 otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn"  
 /> 
 </providers> 
</membership>
```

and

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="LdapRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".PeopleDCRole"> 
 <providers> 
 <add  
name="LdapRoleProvider"  
type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LDAPRoleProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C" 
server="DC" 
port="389" 
useSSL="false" 
groupContainer="DC=userName,DC=local" 
groupNameAttribute="cn" 
groupMemberAttribute="member" 
userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName" 
dnAttribute="distinguishedName" 
groupFilter="(ObjectClass=group)" 
scope="Subtree" 
/> 
 </providers> 
</roleManager>
```

Here is the data I use to access with Ldap Browsers:

```
Host:10.32.192.149 Base DN:dc=mycompany,dc=it Username:uid=MYUSERNAME,ou=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=it Password:MYPASSWORD
```

Once I'm authenticated, I get this set of data in my Ldap browser:

```
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: sambaSamAccount
objectClass: enatelUser
cn: MYUSERNAME
uid: MYUSERNAME
```

Could anyone tell me how to change the xml above? 
For example, I don't know what I should put instead of:

userDNAttribute="distinguishedName"
  userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName"

All I tried didn't work.

**EDIT:**
I have tried, without lsuccess,  inserting the following xml in the web.config files:

```
 <add name="membershipLdap" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" server="myserver" port="389" useSSL="true" userDNAttribute="distinguishedName" useDNAttribute="true" userNameAttribute="uid" userContainer="ou=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=it" userObjectClass="user" userFilter="(ObjectClass=user)" scope="Subtree" otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn" />



            <add name="roleManagerLdap" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapRoleProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" server="myserver" port="389" useSSL="true" enableSearchMethods="true" groupContainer="ou=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=it" groupNameAttribute="Ou" groupNameAlternateSearchAttribute="Ou" groupMemberAttribute="member" userNameAttribute="uid" dnAttribute="distinguishedName" useUserDNAttribute="true" scope="Subtree" userFilter="&amp;(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)" groupFilter="&amp;(objectCategory=Group)(objectClass=group)" />
```

I got the following ULS errors:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_WebTemplateConfiguration()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.InitJs_Register(Page page)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterForControl(Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String language, Boolean injectNoDefer, Boolean controlRegistration, Boolean loadInlineLast, Boolean ignoreFileNotFound)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.Register(Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String language, String uiVersion, String ctag)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.Register(String uiVersion, Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.Register(Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.GetOnDemandScriptKey(String strKey, String strFile, Boolean registerDependencies, Control ctrl, Page page)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterOnDemand(Control ctrl, Page page, String strKey, String strFile, Boolean localizable)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterOnDemand(Page page, String strFile, Boolean localizable)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterForControl(Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String language, Boolean injectNoDefer, Boolean controlRegistration, Boolean loadInlineLast, Boolean ignoreFileNotFound)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.Register(Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String language, String uiVersion, String ctag)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterOnDemand(Control ctrl, Page page, String strKey, String strFile, Boolean localizable)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)    
 at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)


STS Call: Failed to issue new security token. Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException]: The security token username and password could not be validated. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException: The security token username and password could not be validated.).


Token Handler: Claims Forms Sign-In: Membership Provider 'membershipLdap' username-password check for user 'myusername' failed.


An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The security token username and password could not be validated..
```

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Foundation or Server? What attribute do users log in with to OpenLDAP?

Comment: @Trevor Seward I am using SharePoint server. Users usually login with a username and a password. In a script I need to pass uid (so maybe that is the attribute you refer to) ex. with php I pass these parameters:         ldap_bind($ds0, "uid="  . $username . "," .'ou=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=it',  $password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used this document [Configuration Example for OpenLDAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136.aspx)

```
<membership defaultProvider="LdapMembership">
  <providers>
    <add 
    name="LdapMembership"
    type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LDAPMembershipProvider, 
    Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C" 
    server="<server name>" 
    port="389" 
    useSSL="false" 
    useDNAttribute="false" 
    userNameAttribute="uid" 
    userContainer="ou=People,dc=domain,dc=org" 
    userObjectClass="person" 
    userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)" 
    scope="Subtree" 
    otherRequiredUserAttributes="uid,cn" 
    />
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager> 
  <providers>
    <add 
    name="LdapRole" 
    type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LDAPRoleProvider, 
    Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"
    server="<server name>" 
    port="389" 
    useSSL="false" 
    groupContainer="dc=domain,dc=org" 
    userNameAttribute="uid" 
    useUserDNAttribute="false" 
    userFilter="(objectClass=person)" 
    groupNameAttribute="cn" 
    dnAttribute="" 
    scope="Subtree" 
    />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

and I was able to be authenticated with openLdap.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a scenario where you need email to be entered as username .

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager>
      <providers>
        <add name="FabrikamRole" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapRoleProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" server="adlds01.nauplius.local" port="636" useSSL="true" enableSearchMethods="true" groupContainer="CN=SharePoint,DC=Fabrikam,DC=local" groupNameAttribute="cn" groupNameAlternateSearchAttribute="cn" groupMemberAttribute="member" userNameAttribute="mail" dnAttribute="distinguishedName" useUserDNAttribute="true" scope="Subtree" userFilter="&amp;(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)" groupFilter="&amp;(objectCategory=Group)(objectClass=group)" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <add name="FabrikamMembership"  type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" server="adlds01.nauplius.local" port="636" useSSL="true" userDNAttribute="distinguishedName" useDNAttribute="true" userNameAttribute="mail" userContainer="CN=SharePoint,DC=Fabrikam,DC=local" userObjectClass="user" userFilter="(ObjectClass=user)" scope="Subtree" otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web>
```

PS below link it should give you an idea , since i am not sure which verson of sharepoint you using :

http://thesharepointfarm.com/2012/11/sharepoint-2010-and-2013-sample-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-configuration-files/

Comment: the link is not working now (500 internal server error). Anyway I am using SharePoint 2013. I have edited the question with a new attempt based on your answer, which unfortunately is not working

Comment: SecurityTokenServiceApplication sevice is running ? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0fc2f531-1305-44a5-bbea-9ea192c659e8/is-the-security-token-service-in-sharepoint-2010-broken

Comment: Yes @Nikhil Secure Token Service Appplication is running. I can also query the securitytoken.svc and get the wsdl for example